# Google Custom Search and Passing along Querystring Variables

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on a web app project that has been in development for  long time. The app has two sides, the majority of the site is publicly accessible. However, there are sections that require the user to be logged in before they can access certain content.

When the user logs in they get a sessionid (GUID) which is stored in a table in the database which tracks all sort for data about the user and their activity.

Every page of the app was written to look if this session id variable exists or not in the querystring. If a user tries to access one of these protected areas, the app checks to see if this sessiond variable is in the querystring. If i is not, they are redirected to the login screen.

The flow of the site moves has the user moving seamlessly from secured areas to non-secured areas, back and forth, etc.

So we did a test run with the Google Custom Search and it does an awesome job picking up all our dynamic content in these public areas. However, we have not been able to figure out how to pass the sessionid along with the search results **IF** the user is logged in already.

Is it possible to pas querystring variables that already exist in the url along with the search results?

Comment: Why are you storing the session ID in the query string? Cookies are standard for this as of, oh, the last decade or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Google doesn't give you the possibilty to modify the URL's of the Search Results in their Custom Search.

A possible solution would be to store your Session-Key to a Cookie, rather than passing it with every URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parseQueryFromUrl function

```
function parseQueryFromUrl () {
    var queryParamName = "q";
    var search = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var parts = search.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var keyvaluepair = parts[i].split('=');
      if (decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[0]) == queryParamName) {
        return decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Select RESULTS ONLY option in the Look & Feel and it will provide you with the code.
[www.google.com/cse/](http://www.google.com/cse/)